# CSS: '+' and '-' icons to appear as '-' only when opened of accordion

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

Its ok as below:

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/aa.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/aa.png)

The problem: When I click the accodion to open and you can see '+' and '-' icons appeared at the same time. It is because the text heading is spread to two lines. It is ok when it one line only.

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/bb.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/bb.png)

How do I force '+' and '-' icons to appear as '-' only when opened.

I use jQuery 1.7 and it is for iPhone.

This is the CSS:

```
  .trigger {padding:0px;margin:0; background:url(../images/toggle_small.svg) no-repeat right; background-position:100% -20px; } 
  .trigger a{color: #636363;text-decoration: none;display: block; padding:2px 0 2px 0;font-size:16px;font-family:opensans;font-weight:normal; }
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="toogle_wrap">
        <div class="trigger"><a href="#"><span class="trig">8.</span> lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</a></div>
        <div class="toggle_container">
        <ul class="lists">
        <li>Lorem ipsum consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
     $(function() {
         $('#tabsmenu').tabify();
         $(".toggle_container").hide(); 

         $(".trigger").click(function(){
         $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
         return false;
         });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: And what are the relevant classes for the closed, and opened, elements?

Comment: Please include the html that's being used as well.

Comment: I'm guessing by the CSS is that "toggle_small.svg" is setup as a sprite?  And when the container box is large enough, both icons are appearing.  Is that correct?  If so, you might have to separate the icons into 2 files or add more space between your sprites.

Comment: The closed is closed accordion. The opened one where you can see blue '-' icon as well as '+' icon. a '+' icon is not supposed to be visible.

Comment: It is glitch is visible when a test heading is two lines. That what is the problem.

Comment: Yes it is set up as CSS sprite. Can you set it up as background-position? Lets say background-position: 0.625em -2.5em to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a sprite

```
+-----+
|  -  |
|  +  |
+-----+
```

and when the heading breaks onto two lines the other parts of the sprite "bleed" into the view. You just need to increase the padding between the single parts of the sprite.

```
+-----+
|  -  |
|     |
|     |
|  +  |
+-----+
```

This only occurs when it is opened, because the open-icon is placed above the close-icon.

If you dont want to edit the sprite, you can introduce an additional element which holds the icons and declare a fixed height and overflow hidden on it.

```
<div class="toogle_wrap">
        <div class="trigger"><a href="#">...<span class="open"></span></a></div>
```

```css
.open{
   background:      /* declare your background-image here*/
   height:          /* exact height of the - sign*/
   overflow:hidden; /* prevent bleeding*/
}
```

do the same fore the closed-state.

Comment: What about "background-position: 0.625em -2.5em" is that a solution?

Comment: relative positioning won't help. But you can introduce another element - i will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using another sprite

this version is suitable for every height, in difference to Christoph's solution

```
+----------+
|  -       |
|          |
|          |
|       +  |
+----------+
```

Comment: Ok. Is there CSS to go with it?

Comment: Though this is a possible solution in most cases it's not necessary and even not wanted, because it only bloats the sprites. In general you want to keep the padding between the sprites as small as possible. In most cases even a 1px padding should be enough.